# Django, o2o/one-to-one modeling with multiple models

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, foreign-key-relationship

I have a model Job.

```
class Job(models.Model):
  job_number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  date_opened = models.DateField()
  staff_opened = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="jobs_opened")
  date_closed = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
  staff_closed = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="jobs_closed", db_index=True, blank=True, null=True)
  date_promised = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
  date_estimate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

  customer = models.CharField("Customer", max_length=50, db_index=True)
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length=60, unique=True)
```

And I also have a number of different type of jobs that hold more information, depending on what it is:

```
class WorkshopJob(Job):
  job = models.OneToOneField(Job, parent_link=True)
  invoice_number = models.CharField("Invoice Number", max_length=30, blank=True)
  part = models.ForeignKey(PartNumber)
  serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
```

and

```
class EngineeringJob(Job):
  job = models.OneToOneField(Job, parent_link=True)
  work_order = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  reported_fault = models.TextField()
  findings = models.TextField(blank=True)
  work_performed = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

Any particular Job can only have one Engineering Job, one Workshop Job - but it *can* have one of each, too.

I never instantiate a Job on it's own - there is no AddJob view or page - only the subclasses.

The part I'm struggling with is the link - if I am viewing the detail of one subclass, how can I "add" another type of Job to the same Job?

IE if the I had an engineering job with job_id=1, how do I "pass" the job_id=1 to the new Workshop Job in the view?

I've tried adding get_initial(self) to the views, but it isn't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm going to rejig my set up.

Previously I had urls like this:

```
  url(r'^workshop/add/$', views.WorkshopJobAdd.as_view(), name='wsjob_add'),
  url(r'^workshop/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.WorkshopJobDetail.as_view(), name='wsjob_detail'),
  url(r'^workshop/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/edit/$', views.WorkshopJobEdit.as_view(), name='wsjob_edit'),
  url(r'^workshop/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/invoice/$', views.WSJInvoice.as_view(), name='wsj_invoice'),
  url(r'^engineering/add/$', views.EngineeringJobAdd.as_view(), name='wsjob_add'),
  url(r'^engineering/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.EngineeringJobDetail.as_view(), name='wsjob_detail'),
  url(r'^engineering/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/edit/$', views.EngineeringJobEdit.as_view(), name='wsjob_edit'),
  url(r'^engineering/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/invoice/$', views.EngineeringInvoice.as_view(), name='wsj_invoice'),
```

And was trying to pass the job_id between views.

But I think the easiest/sensible solution to my problem is to change the urls to something more like:

```
  url(r'^job/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/workshop/add/$', views.WorkshopJobAdd.as_view(), name='wsjob_add'),
  url(r'^job/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/workshop/$', views.WorkshopJobDetail.as_view(), name='wsjob_detail'),
  url(r'^job/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/workshop/edit/$', views.WorkshopJobEdit.as_view(), name='wsjob_edit'),
  url(r'^job/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/workshop/invoice/$', views.WSJInvoice.as_view(), name='wsj_invoice'),
```

And then adding a new subclassed model to an existing Job would just be a matter of using the slug. I was making things far to hard for myself.

Comment: Turns out this was insufficient. Now I have the same problem as above but refactored.

How do I tell the WorkshopJob CreateView/ModelForm about the already existing Job created via EngineeringJob? I tried get_initial on the CreateView, but I'm obviously not using it correctly since I still fail to have "job" in my kwargs, and I don't know how to make job = request.kwargs['job'] in the CreateView?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is another case of "CBVs aren't always the best solution".

Which is not the end of the world - I think I do wish for an easy way to tell when it's the case though :\